# Why am I unable to set Amazon S3 as a trigger for my Serverless Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I am attempting to set a NodeJS Lambda function to be triggered when an image is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket.  I have seen multiple tutorials and have the yml file set up as shown.  Below is the YML config file:

```
functions:
  image-read:
    handler: handler.imageRead
    events:
      - s3:
        bucket: <bucket-name-here>
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

Is there something I am missing for the configuration? Is there something I need to do in an IAM role to set this up properly?

Comment: Is there some kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

The YAML that you have here looks good but there may be some other problems.

Just to get you started:

- are you deploying the function using the right credentials? (I've seen it many times that people are deploying in some other account etc. than they think - verify in the web console that it's there)
- can you invoke the function in some other way? (from the serverless command line, using http trigger etc.)
- do you see anything in the logs of that function? (add console.log statements to see if anything is being run)
- do you see the trigger installed in the web console?
- can you add trigger manually on the web console?

Try to add a simple function that would only print some logs when it is run and try to add a trigger for that function manually. If it works then try to do the same with the serverless command line but start with a simple function with just one log statement and if it works then go from there.

See also this post for more hints - S3 trigger is not registered after deployment:

- https://forum.serverless.com/t/s3-trigger-is-not-registered-after-deployment/1858